# How can I paste the copied file in working directory using cmd?

Tags: cmd.exe, ms-dos

I want to paste a copied file to current working directory using `cmd`.

like `cmd> paste filename`

not like  `cmd> copy source destination`

Can this be done?

Comment: What is this `paste` command you speak of? Your second approach is how you would do this.  MS-DOS is not aware of your clipboard.

Comment: @Madbreaks: well, it is - kind of. You can write to the clipboard with `clip` or by marking text and press `enter`. You can paste your clipboard with the right mouse button, if it's text. Problem here: if you copy a file in explorer, the content of the clipboard is not text. (what a pity, that microsoft didn't think of implementing a `paste`command too)

Comment: @Stephan: You are right.but can i have any other utility if it is there?

Comment: I'm afraid, no. `cmd` is not able to accept any other object type than text. You can drag and drop "files" from explorer to `cmd` and `cmd` will receive a list of filenames. Then it's your job to do with them, whatever you like. Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27298972/2152082 . I'm no aware about an utility, that does, what you want, but that doesn't mean that there is none somewhere out there.

Comment: Thanx Stephan.:)

Answer (score -1):

This will often accomplish nearly the same thing:

start .

That doesn't paste the file, but it does open up a GUI, so that you can easily paste the file.  If you're trying to avoid typing a bit long path, that can seem to be the fastest way to do things.

I am not familiar with any way to copy from the clipboard using only the internal commands that are built into CMD.EXE, but CMD.EXE can run some external tools.  If you simply like typing commands from CMD.exe, or are seeking to automate in a batch file, then a solution is available.

If you actually have the file in the clipboard (and, to clarify this up front: not a reference/shortcut to the file, like what essentially happens if you used Explorer's Copy/Cut commands on a file...  I mean if you actually have the contents of the file in your clipboard), another option may be to use JP Software's TCC/LE and run:

> copy clip: outputfile

Another alternative that involves using JP Software's TCC/KE is to use the built-in variable @clip[lineNumber].  That can easily be done to get information from a single line file: more lines could be done with some crafty Batch programming.

I realize the question stated that this should be done from cmd.exe.  However, TCC/LE can be run from a cmd.exe command line, so this technically does answer the requested question.  The following shows hot to do this with TCC/LE 64-bit edition (installed to a 64-bit version of Microsoft Windows).

> "C:\Program Files\JPSoft\TCCLE13x64\tcc.exe" /C copy clip: outputfile